# Chrome Extension - Content Security Policy directive (LinkedIn)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am using a chrome extension to parse a username and crosscheck it on my db. However LinkedIns CSP prevents me making GET-calls from the chrome extension.

This is my console error:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://my.api.url/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' wss: static.licdn.com s.c.lnkd.licdn.com static-fstl.licdn.com static-src.linkedin.com dms.licdn.com static-exp1.licdn.com static-exp2.licdn.com s.c.exp1.licdn.com s.c.exp2.licdn.com static-lcdn.licdn.com s.c.lcdn.licdn.com media.licdn.com m.c.lnkd.licdn.com platform.linkedin.com https://www.linkedin.com https://indeed-indeed.p.mashape.com/apisearch cdn.lynda.com media-exp2.licdn.com media-exp1.licdn.com video-uploads-prod.s3.amazonaws.com video-uploads-prod.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com https://media-src.linkedin.com/media/".
```

Is there any way to override this in the meta tags or give chrome extensions extra permissions?

Answer (score 2):

To be able to make GET requests from your extension you should add  `https://my.api.url/` to `connect-src`  in `manifes.json`

```
  "content_security_policy" : " .... connect-src https://my.api.url/ ..."
```